# How to return list item as JSON in ASP.NET MVC using stored procedure result?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I want to return some data from a SQL Server table; I used a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TITILESEARCH]
    (@FLAG INT, 
     @Author VARCHAR(300) = NULL,
     @Category VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
     @Title VARCHAR(MAX) = NUll)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@FLAG = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM SmartLibClientDB.dbo.LibraryMediaEntry 
        WHERE Title LIKE '%' + @Title + '%' 
    END
END
```

On the server-side, the stored procedure is executed like this:

```
var media = new LibraryMediaEntry();
var db = new SchooberrySchoolEntities();

SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Title", "Charpy Impact Test");
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@FLAG", 1);

media = db.Database.SqlQuery<LibraryMediaEntry>("exec SP_TITILESEARCH @Title, @FLAG", param1, param2)
                   .ToList()
                   .FirstOrDefault();   // Getting error when executed
return Json(media, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But the code throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Charpy Impact Test' to data type int.

What I want to do is return the table data as `JSON` is this the correct method to do this? Or why the error? I can't understand what I am doing wrong because the column the error asking to convert to `int` is actually a `varchar` column

Note: I am using a stored procedure because the data I am returning is from a different database on the same server

Comment: Perhaps you should check the "LibraryMediaEntry" table for the data type you used for your "Title" Column

Comment: Also can you explicitly specify the Data type of your parameters. using the "SqlDbType.VarChar" ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find what caused the error but passing all parameters including the null did the job for me

```
var DB = new dbEntities();
                    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@FLAG", 1);
                    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Author", "");
                    SqlParameter Param3 = new SqlParameter("@Category", "");
                    SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@Title", Convert.ToString(id));
                    var medias = db.Database.SqlQuery<LibraryMediaEntry>("exec SP_TITILESEARCH @FLAG,@Author,@Category,@Title", param1, param2, Param3, param4).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Charpy Impact Test' to data type int.

This means that the `@Title` parameter is expecting an `int` (integer). `Charpy Impact Test` is not an integer so your stored procedure call fails.  Picking an integer value is the first step.

> want to do is return the table data as JSON

Your code:

```
 media = db.Database.SqlQuery<LibraryMediaEntry>("exec SP_TITILESEARCH @Title,@FLAG"
  ,param1
  ,param2)
  .ToList()
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

is calling `.FirstOrDefault()` which will result in a singe row in media.  Did you intend to have a single record returned?

Comment: i have updated my stored procedure i have defined that ```@Title``` as ```varchar(Max)``` why then it expect a ```int``` value

Comment: I don't even know how to answer that question.  The only thing I can think of is, are you implying the computer is lying to you about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible issues with your code.

Your stored proc param `@FLAG` is defined as `varchar(25)`.  Yet, when populating it, you are passing an integer (`SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@FLAG",1);`).  Change it to:

var param2 = new SqlParameter("@FLAG", "1");

On the matter of the actual error you are getting...  Check your LibraryMediaEntry object.  Is the property that's getting populated an int by any chance?  That's probably where the problem lies.

Finally, your stored proc.  `SELECT * FROM` is bad form in a stored procedure.  Specify the actual fields you want. It also helps with debugging.